# Automatically naming output files

Tags: csv, export

I was looking for a set of code(s) to make it possible for files to be named with a desired output.

For example:

```
touch ~/Desktop/OutputFileName.txt
```

or

```
touch ~/Desktop/Output.csv
```

Is there a way to name this file with the serial number of the workstation? This way I can run this script centrally and each file get named as the serial of the workstation?

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
import os

workstation = os.environ['COMPUTERNAME']

touch ~/Desktop/%s.csv % workstation
```

or:

```
import socket

workstation = socket.gethostname()

touch ~/Desktop/%s.csv % workstation
```

Hope this helps!